# N tier architecture and ASP.NET datasources

Tags: asp.net, architecture

In sense of separation tiers from each other,is it properly to use a datasource in the ASP web appliaction(presentation tier)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object DataSource, or possibly LINQ DataSource, could be used and arguably be called N-Tier.

But, direct access to the database via a SqlDataSource would not.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen checkists for architecture reviews. One item in those lists is to check for such "tier bypass" actions.

I would say it's not usually proper to allow such direct access. There are exceptions to every rule, but this is one that I would need much persuasion that it's necessary for such direct access.

Answer (score 0):

No, ideally in a n-tier application: your presentation layer should interact with your Business Logic Layer which in turn should interact with the DAL which will communcaiet with your data source, i.e:

Presentation Layer <---> Business Logic later <---> Data Access Layter <--> Database (data source)

Comment: so how would you populate a gridview control ? with properly paging,sorting and filtering. the datasource is doing this all instead of you. i'd like to use one from telerik (radgridview)

Comment: you add some entity class and class collection which inherits from BinsingList<object> which you can bind it to any control (inlcuding gridview). The DAL can load the data in an entity class, which can be carried from DAL to presentation layer.

Comment: what about if i nedd to populate the gridview with 300 000 racords ? Can't imagine to carry this amount of data.How would you do the paging ?

Comment: You plan instead to bring 300,000 records to the desktop?